# Openlayers 3. Clusters

Tags: javascript, styles, cluster-computing, openlayers

I use Openlayers 3. I have a layer with clustering:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: 10,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: []
        })
    })
});
```

I add two features to it this way:

```
this.feature1 = <some feature with style>;
this.feature2 = <some feature with style>;
layer.getSource().getSource().addFeature(this.feature1);
layer.getSource().getSource().addFeature(this.feature2);
```

Then I want to hide my features by setting theire styles to null:

```
this.feature1.setStyle(null);
this.feature2.setStyle(null);
```

So, on the map these features are not visible. But if these features are placed close to each other, the cluster marker is shown. So, my question is the next: is any way not to consider features with empty style in clustering?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a "geometryFunction" parameter whey you create your Cluster source.

This function will get called and give you the ability to determine what should be included in the cluster.

Comment: I have tried it before, but looks like this parameter does not work in my version of OL3. Which version is such parameter available from? I'm using Openlayers 3.7.0